# How to double value if condition happens twice in a row?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, integer, double

I'm making a game with a score text and was wondering how I would write a script that doubles the points added to the score if some condition happens twice in a row? So far, I have a block that adds 2 points instead of 1 if the player gets the bullet in a certain region. The code is as follows:

```
if (-0.02f < transform.forward.x && transform.forward.x < 0.03f) {
    perfectScoreText.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("PerfectHit");
    currentScore += 2;
    scoreText.text = "" + currentScore;
    }
```

I was wondering how I'd make that code add two times as much as the user completes the condition twice/thrice/etc in a row.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Oops sorry... added it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a counter for perfect hit. Lets say `perfectHitCounter`. When perfect hit occurs increase this counter by one, if perfect hit fails make this counter zero. And when it reaches 2, add double score and reset the counter or if your game has the combo system you can increase the counter till you miss the perfect shot.

> PSEUDO

I assume the code you provide is where the perfect hit happens.

```
if (-0.02f < transform.forward.x && transform.forward.x < 0.03f) //Perfect Hit
{
    //Perfect hit
    perfectHitCounter += 1;
    //Add normal score if you wish
}
if('not perfect score condition')
{
    perfectHitCounter = 0;
}
if(perfectHitCounter >= 2)
{
    currentScore += 2;
    //perfectHitCounter = 0; //If there is no combo system.
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!